# Plotting two quant columns into one geom_col graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to produce a bar graph of gapminder data. I need one graph with continents on the x-axis and GDP on the y-axis and within the continent, subsection having a bar for each minimum GDP and maximum GDP.  I really can't figure it out

Here is the dataset:

```
continent   min_GDP    max_GDP
Africa      241.1659    21951.21        
America    1201.6372    42951.65        
Asia       331.0000 113523.13       
Europe     973.5332 49357.19        
Oceania    10039.5956   34435.37
```

This keeps on throwing errors...

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(continent, min_GDP)) +
geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
ylab("GDP") +
xlab("Year")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dataset %>%
    gather(var, Dollars, -continent) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = Dollars, fill = var)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```